# rCharts show in RStudio Viewer, not showing in browser (Chrome)

Tags: r, rcharts

Here is my data

```
new <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Month of 2013-07", "Month of 2013-08", 
"Month of 2013-09", "Month of 2013-10", "Month of 2013-11", "Month of 2013-12"
), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Group 1", "Group 10", 
"Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5", "Group 6", "Group 7", 
"Group 8", "Group 9"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 0.073, 
0.106, 0.056, 0.036, 0.007, 0, 1, 0.006, 0.022, 0.005, 0.038, 
0, 0.867, 1, 0.052, 0, 0.147, 0, 0.005, 0.007, 1, 0.005, 0.003, 
0, 1, 0.474, 0.017, 0, 0.039, 0.026, 0.001, 0.008, 0, 1, 0.01, 
0.004, 0, 0.074, 0.001, 0.003, 1, 0, 0.006, 1, 0.003, 0.012, 
0.011, 0, 0.911, 1, 0.352, 0, 0.27, 0, 0.349, 0.016, 0.101, 1, 
0.845)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

(this is the reproducible data for the chart)

Code to generate the chart:

```
require(rCharts)

inteplot.7 <- rPlot(Var1 ~ Var2, color = 'value', data = new ,type = 'tile')
inteplot.7$guides("{color: {scale: {type: gradient, lower: white, upper: steelblue}}}")
inteplot.7$guides(x = list(levels = c('Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 4', 'Group 5',
                                      'Group 6', 'Group 7', 'Group 8', 'Group 9', 'Group 10')))
inteplot.7
```

Any idea why it is not showing in browser?

(edited) I am using Chrome. Does work in IE. Any solution to make it works in Chrome?
(edited2) options for my markdown

````
```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA, cache = T,echo=F,fig.height=550,out.height=550,fig.width=1000,out.width=1000,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
options(rcharts.mode = 'iframe', rcharts.cdn = TRUE)
    op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')
    inteplot.7$show('iframesrc', cdn = T,static = FALSE)
    ```
````

Comment: I will try with different browser. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Check the browser setting in `options()`

Comment: The polycharts javascript library is throwing an `Uncaught DefinitionError: Bad specification.` in the javascript console in Chrome. You should consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues) for this, since it's not a bug in your code and is still not working even with a fresh github install of rCharts for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have experienced the problem you describe. I have found the following workaround, which also offers what I think is a better workflow.

1. save the chart as a separate html file from within the `r` chunk (instead of attempting to display it 'inline')
2. insert the chart into your html document with `<iframe>`

I think this is better workflow because you can save all your documents' charts with meaningful names and have them at hand for insertion into other documents, should you need to. If your system does not compile a few months from now and a deadline is looming, you'll have the standalone html to go with.

Example:

````
```{r 'Figure_1_1',  results = 'asis', comment = NA, cache = FALSE, fig.height = 5, fig.width = 8} 
require(rCharts)
load("data/df_1_1.Rda") 
# round data for rChart tooltip display
df_1_1$value <- round(df_1_1$value, 2)
n <- nPlot(value ~ Year, group = 'variable', data = df_1_1, type = 'lineChart') 
n$save('figures/Figure_1_1.html', standalone = TRUE)
```
<iframe src ='figures/Figure_1_1.html', width = "860px", height = "450px"></iframe>
````

Note how I'm playing with the r chunk's `fig.height` and `fig.width` (in inches) and the html iframe's `width` and `height` (in pixels), to achieve both high resolution and a fit to the web page dimensions. I'm not sure what the `fig.height` and `fig.height` do to the rChart (if anything), but if you have other type of charts in your document, such as `ggplot2` plots, then you will probably want to set figure dimensions in both `r`  and `html` chunks.

If you get a conflict with `fig.retina` (as I did as a result of setting `out.width` in the `r` chunk), then set it to NULL in the r chunk: `fig.retina = NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
r1 <- rPlot(Var1 ~ Var2, color = 'value', data = new ,type = 'tile')
r1$guides("{color: {scale: {type: gradient, lower: white, upper: steelblue}}}")
r1$guides(x = list(numticks = 10))
r1
```

The trouble with your code was the last line where you specified levels.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it is still not showing in Chrome.

Comment: When you open your Chrome console, are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: Just blank. Uncaught DefinitionError: Bad specification. Got this when i inspect element in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the whitespace in your factor level names is the issue.  Removing all whitespace fixes the problem:

```
library(stringr)
levels(new$Var1) <- str_replace_all(levels(new$Var1), " ", "")
levels(new$Var2) <- str_replace_all(levels(new$Var2), " ", "")

require(rCharts)

inteplot.7 <- rPlot(Var1 ~ Var2, color = 'value', data = new ,type = 'tile')
inteplot.7$guides("{color: {scale: {type: gradient, lower: white, upper:       steelblue}}}")
inteplot.7$guides(x = list(levels = c('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4', 'Group5', 'Group6', 'Group7', 'Group8', 'Group9', 'Group10')))
inteplot.7
```